# C# create pdf documents with no need of High permissions on the server

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I have a C# proyect where I need to create a pdf document. I did it using the iTextSharp dll but when I ran it on the server it didn't work. It seems that the dll needs higher permissions than the one I have on my shared server.

Is there any other free way to do this? I'm trying to create the pdf from a grid I have, I don't care how I create the document (from html, code behind, etc) as long as it works.

does anybody know how to do this?

regards!

Comment: What permission error are you getting?  When does it happen?

Comment: This is a little hard to answer, since you've provided no code, no error messages, or any other useful information. Please edit your question to provide some details that we can us to try and help, or I suspect this will be closed as "not a real question". Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

iTextSharp is just an assembly the contains an API for generating PDF's. It does not require any more privileges than your ASP.NET application.

Are you by chance trying to write the PDF to disk? Your ASP.NET process may not have write access to the location you are writing to.

I would suggest a better way is to output the PDF directly to the Response stream, assuming you are returning the PDF to the web user.

Comment: I try it from many different ways, I try it by showing the pdf on the client, saving it to the users computer but either ways worked.

by any chance, what you mean by output the pdf to the response stream is this...

Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=CedulaJuego.pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(result.ToArray());
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
Response.End();